# Describe the closure of operator S

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, adjoint-operators

Let $(\lambda_n)_{n\in N}$ be an arbitrary sequence in $\mathbb{C}$ and hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_1 := l^2(\mathbb{N})$. Consider the operator $(S,D(S))$:
\begin{align*}
        D(S) := \{x\in\mathcal{H}_1 : \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, x_n = 0 \text{ if } n \geq N\}, \hspace{20pt} Sx := (\lambda_nx_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\,.
    \end{align*}
    Describe the closure of $S$.

---

I know that $S$ is continous, linear and therefore closed. Does $S = \bar{S}$ then apply immediately? Or do I have to do something else? Do I perhaps have to calculate $\bar{S}$ via the adjoint, so $\bar{S} = S^{**}$?

Comment: Why do you say it's continuous? What do you know about the $\lambda_n$?

Comment: The operator $S$ is bounded:
    \begin{align*}
        ||{Sx}||_{\mathcal{H}_1} = ||{(\lambda_nx_n)_n}||_{\mathcal{H}_1} = \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,|\lambda_nx_n|^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{n=N}^\infty\,|\lambda_nx_n|^2} \leq \sup_{n \leq N}\,\lambda_n \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{n=N}^\infty\,|x_n|^2} = \sup_{n \leq N}\,\lambda_n \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{n=N}^\infty\,|x_n|^2} = \sup_{n \leq N}\,\lambda_n \cdot ||{x}||_{D(S)}\,.
    \end{align*}
The norm in the space $D(S)$ is identical with the norm from $\mathcal{H}_1$ (i.e. the $l^2$ norm), there applies: $D(S) \subset \mathcal{H}_1$.

Comment: Furthermore, the operator is linear:
    \begin{align*}
        &S(\lambda x) = (\lambda_n\lambda x_n)_n = \lambda (\lambda_nx_n)_n = \lambda\,S(x)\,. \\
        &S(x+y) = (\lambda_n(x_n+y_n))_n = (\lambda_nx_n)_n + (\lambda_ny_n)_n = S(x) + S(y)\,.
    \end{align*}
    Thus $S \in \mathcal{L}(D(S),\mathcal{H}_1)$ is linear and bounded, so $S$ is uniformly continuous in $D(S)$. After the theorem of the closed graph, the corresponding graph $G_S$ is a closed subspace.  Finally $S$ is closed.

Comment: $N$ Is arbitrary

Comment: You mean, that $N$ can be $\infty$?

Comment: $N$ can be arbitrarily large and so can $\lambda_n$

Answer (score 1):

You don't know that $S$ is continuous. In fact, it will not not be continuous. For an easy example, take $\lambda_n=n$ for all $n$.

To look at the closure, we look at the graph of $S$: that is 
$$
\{(x,Sx):\ x\in D(S)\}.
$$
Suppose now that $(x^m,Sx^m)\to (x,y)$ with $x^m\in D(S)$ for all $m$. Note that 
$$
y_n=\lim_m(Sx^m)_n=\lim_m\lambda_nx^m_n=\lambda_n\lim_m x^m_n=\lambda_n x_n.
$$
Since $y\in\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, we have 
$$\tag1
\sum_n|\lambda_n|^2|x_n|^2<\infty.
$$
Condition $(1)$ is also sufficient, so 
$$
D(\bar S)=\{x:\ \sum_n|\lambda_n|^2|x_n|^2<\infty\}
$$
and 
$$
\bar S x=(\lambda_nx_n). 
$$

Comment: The linear operator $S$ is bounded:
    \begin{align*}
        ||{Sx}||_{\mathcal{H}_1} = ||{(\lambda_nx_n)_n}||_{\mathcal{H}_1} = \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,|\lambda_nx_n|^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N\,|\lambda_nx_n|^2} = \sup_{n \leq N}\,\lambda_n \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N\,|x_n|^2} = \sup_{n \leq N}\,\lambda_n \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,|x_n|^2} = \sup_{n \leq N}\,\lambda_n \cdot ||{x}||_{D(S)}\,.
    \end{align*}
The norm in the room $D(S)$ is identical with the norm from $\mathcal{H}_1$ (i.e. the $l^2$ norm), there applies: $D(S) \subset \mathcal{H}_1$.

Comment: Thus $S \in \mathcal{L}(D(S),\mathcal{H}_1)$ is linear and bounded, so $S$ is uniformly continuous in $D(S)$. After the theorem of closed graphs, the corresponding graph $G_S$ is a closed subspace.  Finally $S$ is closed.

Comment: @Bayro: "arbitrary sequence" does not mean that it is bounded. For instance $\lambda_n=n$ for all $n$ gives you an unbounded operator.